# Can I use pkg-config commands with XCode?

Tags: xcode, linker, pkg-config

I used to have a compile line like this:

```
g++ opencv_test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

However in XCode, I have to set include paths, library paths and the concrete .dylib's I want to link against. If I change library version, I have to re-populate all the .dylib's manually. I could spare this effort once I could use `pkg-config`.

So do you know any way `pkg-config` (or some apropriate alternative) could be used with an XCode project?